# Help identifying minifigs and pieces of sets - purple character with grey horns and red eyes, cyborg type skull, astronauts light up with moving knees

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands, minifigure-identification

I've got some doozies I've tried identifying. Please see photos but basically a purple guy with horns and yellow teeth, a cyborg type skull (could be a combo), astronauts with moving knees and wearing jetpack things which light up.

Also bonus round two random pieces - window with writing and a green tile with sticker of world and yellow box.

Take it a away and thanks in advance as always!  [image]

Comment: Two minifigures with light up are not LEGO items.

Comment: The knees really give it away.

Comment: I suspect the astronauts are from korean "oxford" brand, given the knees. See http://thebrickblogger.com/2017/11/extra-posable-minifigures-by-oxford/ .

Answer (score 7):

Head and torso from purple minifigure belong to [Zurg](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=toy005#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from Toy Story

[image]

Second minifigure is mixture of several minifgures.

Its **head** is [Minifigure, Head Alien Skull with Red Eyes, Metal Eyebrows with Rivets and Metal Jaw with Screws Pattern - Hollow Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb1084#T=C) that has been part of two [skeletons](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626cpb1084&in=M).

[image]

**Hair** piece is [Minifigure, Hair Short Tousled with Silver Robot Components and Eyepiece Pattern Left Side](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15617pb01&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

[image]

**Torso** is [Torso Ninjago with Red Wires and Mechanical Parts Pattern / Black Arm Left / Flat Silver Arm Right / Yellow Hand Left / Black Hand Right](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb1577c01&idColor=11#T=C&C=11) with its hand changed to Dark Bluish colored versions.

[image]

Both head piece and torso belong to [Cyrus Borg (OverBorg) - Rebooted](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=njo088#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

**Legs** are [Hips and Legs with Red Belt, Red Tassels and Silver Outlined Knee Pads Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=115622#T=C&C=11)

[image]

Additional parts are:

[Glass for Window 1 x 4 x 3 - Opening with Computer Screen with Silver 'ULTRA INTEL' and Ultra Agents Logo Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=133132#T=C&C=15)

[Tile 2 x 2 with Groove with Barcode and Box and Arrows and Globe on Green Background Pattern (Sticker) - Set 60101](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3068bpb1007#T=C&C=6)

Comment: Damn, you beat me to the ninjago minifig by half a minute :-D

Answer (score 5):

The two Astronauts on the right are Laser Pegs figures

The white one is from Laser Pegs Mars Rocket
[image: Laser Pegs Mars Rocket]

The blue one is from Laser Pegs Mission Control
[image]